# Double Refreshing the page on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Having a little hard time doing what I want to achieve.

I am using googlesheets as database, with autosort function to sort the products.

In flutter, after editing 3 products, the flutter app stops "refreshing" so It stops updating inside the app, but in the googlesheets it's always updating.

This is what I currently have to edit the date.

```
Future<void> _updateDate(
                                  BuildContext context) async {
                                final DateTime? nD =
                                    await showDatePicker(
                                        context: context,
                                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                        firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
                                        lastDate: DateTime(2100));

                                if (nD != oD) {
    
                                  await widget.provider
                                      .pushNewDate(_nDF, index);

                                  
                                  setState(() {});

                         //this is what I added after changing some code
                           Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1),
                           (() => (setState(() {}))));
                           ///
                                  
     
                                }
                              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long time I figured it out it was not on my end bue on google sheets that took a litle time to update. I went for another route!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the _updateDate in a set state it will propably work . If it doesnt try _updateDate.then(SetState(){});

Comment: Nope, still didn't work.

Comment: Can you maybe send the full code to see if the problem is coming from somewhere else